# Codeigniter Memcached not connecting to AWS Elasticache Instance

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

**TL;DR:** I've set up AWS ElastiCache and connected via SSH through EC2. But when I try to connect with my Codeigniter application (in the same EC2 instance) it fails and shows that it's attempting to connect to:

```
["localhost:11211"]
```

Why? Shouldn't it be:

```
["****.****.sae1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211"]
```

**So here's the background:**

I'm using **Codeigniter 2.1.4** with **PHP 5.5** in an application I manage, and I want to save some data on an Elasticache instance using Memcached.

My application is running on an Elastic Beanstalk environment, the Elasticache instance is in the same security group as the EB's EC2 instance, and I've set a rule to open all TCP connections.

Memcached is activated as we can see running phpinfo:

```
memcached support       enabled
Version                 2.2.0
libmemcached version    1.0.8
SASL support            yes
Session support         yes
igbinary support        yes
json support            yes
msgpack support         no
```

When I SSH into this instance I can connect to the Elasticache instance using telnet:

```
#telnet ****.****.sae1.cache.amazonaws.com 11211
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
Connected to ****.****.sae1.cache.amazonaws.com.
```

On my application side, I have configured **application/config/staging/memcached.php** like this:

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'default' => array(
        'host'      => '****.****.sae1.cache.amazonaws.com',
        'port'      => 11211,
        'weight'    => 1
    )
);
```

And on the controller:

```
public function memcached(){
    $this->load->driver('cache');
    if($this->cache->memcached->is_supported()){
       $data = $this->cache->memcached->get('foo');
       if (!$data){
          echo 'cache miss!<br />';
          $data = 'bar';
          $this->cache->memcached->save('foo',$data, 60);
       }
       echo $data;
       echo '<pre>';
       var_dump($this->cache->memcached->cache_info());
       echo '</pre>';
    }
}
```

And the output always say that I'm trying to connect to localhost and not to Elasticache, why?? Here's the output:

```
cache miss!
bar
array(1) {
  ["localhost:11211"]=>
  array(24) {
    ["pid"]=>
    int(-1)
    ["uptime"]=>
    int(0)
    ["threads"]=>
    int(0)
    ["time"]=>
    int(0)
    ["pointer_size"]=>
    int(0)
    ["rusage_user_seconds"]=>
    int(0)
    ["rusage_user_microseconds"]=>
    int(0)
    ["rusage_system_seconds"]=>
    int(0)
    ["rusage_system_microseconds"]=>
    int(0)
    ["curr_items"]=>
    int(0)
    ["total_items"]=>
    int(0)
    ["limit_maxbytes"]=>
    int(0)
    ["curr_connections"]=>
    int(0)
    ["total_connections"]=>
    int(0)
    ["connection_structures"]=>
    int(0)
    ["bytes"]=>
    int(0)
    ["cmd_get"]=>
    int(0)
    ["cmd_set"]=>
    int(0)
    ["get_hits"]=>
    int(0)
    ["get_misses"]=>
    int(0)
    ["evictions"]=>
    int(0)
    ["bytes_read"]=>
    int(0)
    ["bytes_written"]=>
    int(0)
    ["version"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Sorry about the loong question guys. But I'd appreciate any thoughts on this.

Cheers.

Comment: At least is entering to this condition `if($this->cache->memcached->is_supported()){`...did you restart the apache service?....sometimes when we use cache we need to restart the apache service in order to reflect those changes :)

Comment: Thanks @Hackerman! Just tried that and still the same output. Cheers

Comment: How are you managing your, mmmm, routing, did you have a firewall rule that redirect all http request to your site first to your cache server...I mean, you have that part cover, right?

Comment: I'm actually saving on Elasticache all the data that is generated in the controller and passed as $this->data['item'] to the view. So if the cache server has that value stored my controller won't need to query my database. So no firewall or HTTP rules. Did I get your question right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your `memcached.php` file, like:

```
$config['memcached'] = array(
  'hostname' => '****.****.sae1.cache.amazonaws.com',
  'port' => 11211,
  'weight' => 1
);
```

And on your `memcached` function:

```
$this->load->driver('cache', array('adapter' => 'memcached', 'backup' => 'dummy'));
```

Comment: Dude. Thank you so much. Your config file did it! I didn't even had to edit my function. Cheers!

Comment: I am glad to help @grpaiva :)

Comment: how can I do that in autoload file?

Comment: @Diego, maybe you can create a new question with all the background and paste the link here....basically, when you create a custom config file like the `memcached.php` and you pace it under `application/config/`...in order to autoload it, you need to add this line to your `autoload.php` file `$autoload['config'] = array('memcached');`